# Connecting Jconsole to a remote JVM over SSH

Tags: java, jmx

I  am trying to connect to a  remote java app using jconsole  as a JMX client over ssh

I  have built  the  CustomAgent described on https://blogs.oracle.com/jmxetc/entry/connecting_through_firewall_using_jmx

The code  for  the  agent  is  here

```
/**
* CustomAgent.java

* https://blogs.oracle.com/jmxetc/entry/connecting_through_firewall_using_jmx
*/

package example.rmi.agent;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.lang.management.ManagementFactory;
import java.net.InetAddress;
import java.rmi.registry.LocateRegistry;
import java.util.HashMap;
import javax.management.MBeanServer;
import javax.management.remote.JMXConnectorServer;
import javax.management.remote.JMXConnectorServerFactory;
import javax.management.remote.JMXServiceURL;

/**
 * This CustomAgent will start an RMI COnnector Server using only
 * port "example.rmi.agent.port".
 *
 * @author dfuchs
 */
public class CustomAgent {

    private CustomAgent() { }

    public static void premain(String agentArgs) 
    throws IOException {

        // Ensure cryptographically strong random number generator used
        // to choose the object number - see java.rmi.server.ObjID
        //
        System.setProperty("java.rmi.server.randomIDs", "true");

        // Start an RMI registry on port specified by example.rmi.agent.port
        // (default 3000).
        //
        final int port= Integer.parseInt(
                System.getProperty("example.rmi.agent.port","3000"));
        System.out.println("Create RMI registry on port "+port);
        LocateRegistry.createRegistry(port);


        // Retrieve the PlatformMBeanServer.
        //
        System.out.println("Get the platform's MBean server");
        MBeanServer mbs = ManagementFactory.getPlatformMBeanServer();

        // Environment map.
        //
        System.out.println("Initialize the environment map");
        HashMap<String,Object> env = new HashMap<String,Object>();

        // This where we would enable security - left out of this
        // for the sake of the example....
        //

        // Create an RMI connector server.
        //
        // As specified in the JMXServiceURL the RMIServer stub will be
        // registered in the RMI registry running in the local host on
        // port 3000 with the name "jmxrmi". This is the same name the
        // out-of-the-box management agent uses to register the RMIServer
        // stub too.
        //
        // The port specified in "service:jmx:rmi://"+hostname+":"+port
        // is the second port, where RMI connection objects will be exported.
        // Here we use the same port as that we choose for the RMI registry. 
        // The port for the RMI registry is specified in the second part
        // of the URL, in "rmi://"+hostname+":"+port
        //
        System.out.println("Create an RMI connector server");
        final String hostname = InetAddress.getLocalHost().getHostName();
        //JMXServiceURL url =
        //    new JMXServiceURL("service:jmx:rmi://"+hostname+
        //    ":"+port+"/jndi/rmi://"+hostname+":"+port+"/jmxrmi");

        //Added to allow  connection through a firewall
        // We use (port+1) to export the RMI connection objects
        JMXServiceURL url =
            new JMXServiceURL("service:jmx:rmi://"+hostname+
            ":"+(port+1)+"/jndi/rmi://"+hostname+":"+port+"/jmxrmi");




        // Now create the server from the JMXServiceURL
        //
        JMXConnectorServer cs =
            JMXConnectorServerFactory.newJMXConnectorServer(url, env, mbs);

        // Start the RMI connector server.
        //
        System.out.println("Start the RMI connector server on port "+port);
        cs.start();
    }
}
```

The  build script  is  here

```
<project name="Agent" basedir="." default="main">

    <property name="src.dir"     value="src"/>
    <property name="build.dir"   value="build"/>
    <property name="classes.dir" value="${build.dir}/classes"/>
    <property name="jar.dir"     value="${build.dir}/jar"/>
    <property name="main-class"  value="example.rmi.agent.CustomAgent"/>

    <target name="clean">
        <delete dir="${build.dir}"/>
    </target>

    <target name="compile">
        <mkdir dir="${classes.dir}"/>
        <javac srcdir="${src.dir}" destdir="${classes.dir}"/>
    </target>

    <target name="jar" depends="compile">
        <mkdir dir="${jar.dir}"/>
        <jar destfile="${jar.dir}/${ant.project.name}.jar" basedir="${classes.dir}">
            <manifest>
                <attribute name="Main-Class" value="${main-class}"/>
            </manifest>
        </jar>
    </target>    

    <target name="run" depends="jar">
        <java jar="${jar.dir}/${ant.project.name}.jar" fork="true"/>
    </target>    
    <target name="clean-build" depends="clean,jar"/>    
    <target name="main" depends="clean,run"/>

     <!-- Builds dist.agent.jar -->    
    <target name="build-agent-jar" description="build an agent jar that can be used with -javaagent"   depends="compile">
        <mkdir dir="${jar.dir}"/>
        <jar basedir="${classes.dir}"  destfile="${jar.dir}/${ant.project.name}.jar">
                <manifest>
                    <attribute name="Premain-Class" value="example.rmi.agent.CustomAgent"/>
                </manifest>
        </jar>
        <echo>To use this application with agent try:</echo>
        <echo>java -Dexample.rmi.port=3000 -javaagent:${dist.agent.jar} -classpath [application-classpath] [application-classpath] [application-main-class]</echo>
    </target>
</project>
```

I   start  the application on the remote machine using

> java -javaagent:agents/build/jar/Agent.jar 
>   -Dexample.rmi.agent.port=6004  -server -server   -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.authenticate="false"  -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote="true" -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.ssl="false"  -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.local.only="false" -jar  path-to-my-app/app.jar

Two ports open on the  host machine, 6004 and  6005 and I  can connect to the application through jconsole  if  the  jconsole is  local to the application.

I then create 2 ssh  tunnels

> ssh  tunnels  ssh -L 6004:localhost:6004  foo@server  ssh  tunnels 
>   ssh -L 6005:localhost:6005  foo@server

The  tunnels are created successfully. I can telnet in on these  ports.

Now the problem is that I  can not  connect remotely using  Jconsole  though

> service:jmx:rmi://localhost:6005/jndi/rmi://localhost:6004/jmxrmi

jconsole  was started by:

> jconsole -J-Djava.util.logging.config.file=logging.properties  -debug

The  error log  is:

> ```
> Dec 18, 2011 4:57:46 PM RMIConnector connect
> FINER: [javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnector: jmxServiceURL=service:jmx:rmi://localhost:6005/jndi/rmi://localhost:6004/jmxrmi]
> ```
>
> connecting...
>       Dec 18, 2011 4:57:46 PM RMIConnector connect
>       FINER: [javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnector: jmxServiceURL=service:jmx:rmi://localhost:6005/jndi/rmi://localhost:6004/jmxrmi]
>   finding stub...
>       Dec 18, 2011 4:58:49 PM RMIConnector connect
>       FINER: [javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnector: jmxServiceURL=service:jmx:rmi://localhost:6005/jndi/rmi://localhost:6004/jmxrmi]
>   connecting stub...
>       Dec 18, 2011 4:58:49 PM RMIConnector connect
>       FINER: [javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnector: jmxServiceURL=service:jmx:rmi://localhost:6005/jndi/rmi://localhost:6004/jmxrmi]
>   getting connection...
>       Dec 18, 2011 4:59:52 PM RMIConnector connect
>       FINER: [javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnector: jmxServiceURL=service:jmx:rmi://localhost:6005/jndi/rmi://localhost:6004/jmxrmi]
>   failed to connect: java.rmi.ConnectException: Connection refused to
>   host: 172.16.0.111; nested exception is: 
>         java.net.ConnectException: Connection timed out
>       java.rmi.ConnectException: Connection refused to host: 172.16.0.111; nested exception is: 
>         java.net.ConnectException: Connection timed out
>         at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPEndpoint.newSocket(TCPEndpoint.java:619)
>         at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPChannel.createConnection(TCPChannel.java:216)
>         at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPChannel.newConnection(TCPChannel.java:202)
>         at sun.rmi.server.UnicastRef.invoke(UnicastRef.java:128)
>         at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIServerImpl_Stub.newClient(Unknown
>   Source)
>         at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnector.getConnection(RMIConnector.java:2343)
>         at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnector.connect(RMIConnector.java:296)
>         at javax.management.remote.JMXConnectorFactory.connect(JMXConnectorFactory.java:267)
>         at javax.management.remote.JMXConnectorFactory.connect(JMXConnectorFactory.java:226)
>         at sun.tools.jconsole.ProxyClient.tryConnect(ProxyClient.java:366)
>         at sun.tools.jconsole.ProxyClient.connect(ProxyClient.java:316)
>         at sun.tools.jconsole.VMPanel$2.run(VMPanel.java:298)
>       Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection timed out
>         at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Native Method)
>         at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:327)
>         at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:193)
>         at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:180)
>         at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:384)
>         at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:546)
>         at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:495)
>         at java.net.Socket.(Socket.java:392)
>         at java.net.Socket.(Socket.java:206)
>         at sun.rmi.transport.proxy.RMIDirectSocketFactory.createSocket(RMIDirectSocketFactory.java:40)
>         at sun.rmi.transport.proxy.RMIMasterSocketFactory.createSocket(RMIMasterSocketFactory.java:146)
>         at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPEndpoint.newSocket(TCPEndpoint.java:613)
>         ... 11 more

Answer (score 2):

I  needed  to add

> -Djava.rmi.server.hostname=localhost

to the  java -server parameters

Comment: Yes, In case you have multiple network adapters. You need to specify the IP Address of the adapter on which you are listening for the remote connection using the above property.

Answer (score 1):

BTW second port now supported directly by the Hotspot 7 JVM - http://dimovelev.blogspot.de/2013/10/out-of-box-jmx-over-firewall-in-hotspot.html

Answer (score 0):

Try running your server with following options:

```
-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote
-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.port=6004
-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.rmi.port=6004
-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.ssl=false 
-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.authenticate=false 
-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.local.only=true
```

Once you have a tunnel for 6004 try this with jconsole:

```
jconsole -J-DsocksProxyHost=127.0.0.1 -J-DsocksProxyPort=6004 service:jmx:rmi:///jndi/rmi://0.0.0.0:6004/jmxrmi -J-DsocksNonProxyHosts=
```